# How do I setup a script to run on a schedule in a clean & professional way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gcp

I have a small python piece of code that I want to run on a schedule. The dirty way to do it would be to just spin up an EC2 instance and use CRON to run the script.

But I was wondering if there's a better (cleaner) way to do this

Also I was wondering how to do the same but on Google Cloud as well as AWS

Comment: Update: I found this Google Cloud article that has a good explanation. https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/how-to-schedule-a-recurring-python-script-on-gcp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWS Lambda should be an obvious choice together with a a CloudWatch Event trigger https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html .

Running an EC2 instance may be reasonable in some scenarios as well. It would make sense for me if the trigger for example did some complex data manipulation on a reasonable small data set (fitting in memory on a bigger spot multi-core instance or something like that).

Running a Fargate task - may be reasonable as well.

If it is something close to the gcloud example I would go with Lambda + CloudWatch Event. All of this can be easily defined via CloudFormation template .

Comment: GCP's answer to Lambda is Cloud Functions. You find find them in the console under "Serverless"

Comment: you can utilize, kubernetes `jobs` as well.